# How to trigger BAT file to run on a remote Windows server from a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, batch-file, ftp, windows-server

My colleague set up a BAT file on a Windows server with an FTP service to collect files every morning from a local network disk drive for me to use in a Rails app. I'm using the Ruby ftp commands and a Sidekicq job to collect the files every morning for parsing into my database.

However, if the service that creates the files fails, I need a way to re-run his BAT file script before the user activates the manual import button that re-runs the importer function in my app.

How can we send a command from the Rails app to the Windows server to activate the BAT file so the files will be fresh?

Comment: This is a Ruby on Rails question and has nothing to do with batchfile, ftp, or Windows Server. Your colleague would have done a FTP client. **You want to know how to exec a program in RUBY.** Batchfile people, Windows people wouldn't have a clue about RUBY a NON windows program.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Unfortunately, we can't use FTP to get the files.